# mysql select from where a condition is met

Tags: mysql

My table structure is as follows

```
ProductID |  Image  | Default
1            1.jpg     N
1            2.jpg     Y
1            3.jpg     N
2            4.jpg     N
2            5.jpg     N
3            6.jpg     Y
3            7.jpg     N
```

I'm Trying to get a return of all producID where there is no default image 'N' , e.g. the above should return productID 2. Sorry no code attempt , as i'm not sure what to do at all.

Comment: Where there is only `N` in the `Default` column for *any* of the `ProductID` values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by the product and select only those having none `default=Y`

```
select productID
from your_table
group by productID
having sum(`default` = 'Y') = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.productID
FROM yourtable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 'DEFAULT'
    FROM yourtable t2
    WHERE T2.productid = t1.productid
    AND T2.`default` = 'Y'
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
This SQL code does what you want:

SELECT productID FROM  
    (SELECT productID, SUM(table.default = 'Y') AS Y_count 
    FROM table
    GROUP BY productID) AS tbl
WHERE Y_count = 0
```

Comment: Code-only answers are frowned upon, please add a short explanation on what this query does.

Answer (score -2):

If default is a column in your database you can use:

```
Select * from mytabale where 'Default'='Y'
```